# Regex in Tcl not working

Tags: regex, string, list, tcl

I am trying to match two strings ....one of the  string i am getting from list and other one is declared by me.

```
set name " HTTP REQUEST = 1\n HTTP REQUEST(SUCCESS) = 0\nSERVER CONN = 1"
set pattern "HTTP REQUEST(SUCCESS)*"
set List [split $name "\n"]
foreach var $List {
    set var [lindex $List 1]
    #set var2 [string trim $var1 " "]

}    
puts $var
if {[regexp $var $pattern match]} {
    puts " matched!" 
    puts $match
} else {
    puts " not matched!"
}
```

Comment: The parentheses must be escaped - `set pattern "HTTP REQUEST\\(SUCCESS\\)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors:

- Parentheses must be escaped with literal backslashes
- The text input should go *after* the pattern in a `regexp` call

So use

```
set pattern {HTTP REQUEST\(SUCCESS\)}
                         ^        ^
```

and then

```
if {[regexp $pattern $var match]} {
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [this code demo](http://ideone.com/Rwqra3)